# Cannot save prepopulated sql database to core data sql database: managedObjectModel not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

my program needs to take a prepopulated sql database and then save the records to the app's database. Unfortunately for some reason the application quits in this method in the application delegate:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Core Data stack
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (managedObjectModel_ != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel_;
}
NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iProspectLite" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
managedObjectModel_ = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
return managedObjectModel_;
}
```

it seems as if the application cannot find a valid managedObjectModel_, or it doesn't exist, or is not creating one. How do i solve this?

one of the error messages I get on the console is this:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception reason: [NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]

part of this I have narrowed down to the NSManagedObject, in that there doesn't seem to be one created or found.

Other information that may be helpful:
I added an entity and defined attributes as described in many other core-data tutorials
the following is the class that defines my entity:

```
#import "Mine.h"


@implementation Mine 

@dynamic primarykey;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic firstCommodity;
@dynamic longitude;
@dynamic county;
@dynamic secondCommodity;
@dynamic latitude;
@dynamic thirdCommodity;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that your trying to load your model file from the path to an SQL persistent store inside the app bundle. Stores and model files are two separate types of files with two separate functions. You can't initialize a NSManagedObjectModel instance from an SQL file and vice versa because the two file types hold completely different information.

You need to change the `pathForResource:` to look for the right file. The file type is `mom` and the default name is the app name so you should use something like:

```
NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AppName" ofType:@"mom"];
```

(If you named you model something else, use that name.)

All this has nothing to do with importing an existing SQL file. However, you will need to fix this before importing the SQL as other's have suggested.

Comment: ok that makes more sense. I changed the strings to my App name and mom, and now when the program crashes it gives me this error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
Which leads me to believe that it cannot find the mom file. Which is weird. Heck I cant seem to find a mom file anywhere on my mac, so maybe core-data is not making such a file?

Comment: In your project in code, you will have file with an extension of `xcdatamodel` (it's the one with you entity graph.) The `mom` file in the build will have the same name as that file. You can also use `modelByMergingModels:` which will automatically locate all the model files for you.

Comment: I selected yours as the answer because it was the closest to what I found worked. it had to be pathForResource:@"AppName" ofType:@"momd"

Comment: The `momd` is a versioned model file.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you getting the pre-populated SQLite database?  If it is not created with Core Data then it is not going to work.  Core Data can only read SQLite files that are created with Core Data.

Comment: I am getting it from the USGS website. What I am doing is loading it directly using sql statements in the application, creating objects out of that data, and then storing them in core data.

Comment: So in effect I am not using coredata to read the populated database, but I am using coredata to store it in another database for future use in my program.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [Core Data Development Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html):

> Compiling a Data Model
>
> A data model is
>   a deployment resource. In addition to
>   details of the entities and properties
>   in the model, a model you create in
>   Xcode contains information about the
>   diagram—its layout, colors of
>   elements, and so on. This latter
>   information is not needed at runtime.
>   The model file is compiled to remove
>   the extraneous information and make
>   runtime loading of the resource as
>   efficient as possible. The `xcdatamodel`
>   "source" file is compiled into a mom
>   deployment file using the model
>   compiler, `momc`.

In other words, Managed Object Models are "compiled" from Xcode Data Model "source" by Xcode during the build process, and that `.mom` file is placed inside the application bundle. So you may need to create a Data Model file manually.

To work around this, I use a Core Data-savvy command line tool to pre-populate the SQLite database files I use with my iPhone projects.

**Edit:**

If Mr. Zarra is correct (and he usually is), then you should write a command line tool in the manner I described, to open the existing database and then pre-populate a new SQLite database file with Core Data. It's a bit of a pain, but it will work.

Comment: I thought I already created a datamodel. 
I added an entity, and attributes to the datamodel, as well as a class specific for that entity as described in a core data tutorial.

Comment: Check the application bundle in your build directory. Is there a `.mom` file present? (Right-click on Target, Reveal in Finder, right-click on .app, Show Package Contents) If not, and you're sure you have an `xcdatamodel`, then make sure the `xcdatamodel` file is listed under the "Compile Sources" section of your Target.

Comment: Right clicking on the target on xcode does not bring up a reveal in finder option. however searching through my computer's files I could not find a .mom file.

Comment: Right click on *the* target, and you will get the menu I described.

Comment: as in the blue thing that bears the title of my app? opening that in finder, and opening package contents shows only three files of extentions .mode1v3 , .pbxuser , and  .pbxproj

Comment: No. That is the project, although you're looking at the Groups & Files pane, which is the right ballpark. Scroll down to the "Targets" entry, and click the disclosure triangle. You'll see a target bearing the name of your app. Right-click on that.

Comment: It does not give me the option to reveal it in finder.